# Parametrization of arbitrary objects to display on an x-y-scope

Tags: geometry, fourier-analysis, parametric

I am trying to find an approach for general parametrization of an arbitrary geometric object or closed curve. Though I am not sure if I am on the right path with that. Basically I have an geometric object which I want to display on an x-y-scope, so I need to calculate according x and y signals (i.e. periodic functions) to reproduce that geometric object.

A circle is probably the easiest example, but how would I go about a rectangle? The answer is two square waves with a phase difference of pi but how would I calculate this?

Comment: Can you give one concrete more detailed example?

Comment: When x=sin(w*t) and y=cos(w*t) or vice versa I will get a circle, when I take the Fourier expansion of a triangle wave and send it to x and with a phase difference of pi to y, I will get a rectangle which its diagonal on the x=0-line. I want to throw in a shape and get the x and y signals.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "x and y signals". Are you looking for parametric equations $\gamma(s) = (x(s),y(s))$? Regardless, the answer will depend on how the "geometric object" is given. How do you have the shapes described?

Comment: It seems to me you want to know how you can find out the parametrization, given that you know the geometric curve, is that right? You won't find a unique method (if any) since several different parametriszation gives the same geometric shape.

Comment: I guess I should rather speak of x(t) and y(t) as functions. The description of  my geometric object is not determined yet, it could be a set of vectors, or whatever is practical. I may have to add: I simply want to display funny shapes on my scope in x-y-mode, so the method doesn't need to be unique and approximations are very acceptable too.

Comment: The approximations or "way of figuring out" $x(t),y(t)$ will depend exclusively on your previous description of the object. You should look more into this so we can answer!